# Vanilla TeX Live 2009 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, latex, texlive

I installed TeX Live 2009 by following the instructions at http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall. Then, to make my local TeX Live installation work with the Ubuntu package management system, I followed the instructions on http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html. That is, I performed the following steps.

```
$ sudo aptitude install equivs
$ mkdir /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs
$ equivs-control texlive-local
# I replaced the contents of texlive-local by http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian-control-ex.txt
$ equivs-build texlive-local
$ sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2009-1~1_all.deb
```

However, when I go about installing kile through the Ubuntu package management system, it requires me to install a lot of dependencies that are already provided by my texlive-local package. Does any one have a suggestion to fix this problem?

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of a question posted on the Tex, LaTeX and Friends StackEchange site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/1094#1094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texlive-local must provide: texlive-base-bin, texlive-latex-base.

The other stuff that gets pulled in are recommends & suggests:

$ sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install kile

Should do the trick =)